# How to load saved data into the CKEditor?

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I know how to save the data in CKEditor4 into MySQL.

But how do I go the other way? That is how do I bring the saved data from my database into the editor for editing?

Or another way of putting it: Say I want to bring up the editor with 
   `<p>Hello world!</p>` 
already in the source of CKEditor. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: ofcourse you are using `textarea` which then will be replace by `ckeditior script` you just need to put your data between start and end tag of `textarea` . `<textarea>$data['my_ckeditor_data_from_mysql']</textarea>`

Comment: Oh it was that simple? Worked a charm. Thank you!